# Android Studio shows error for every line

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio showing error for all lines in the project. I am able to run the app in the device. I tried invalidate cache and restart, that didn't help. Please check the screenshot below.

[image]

I believe, it is something related gradle or android studio!! But not sure where to make changes.
Android Studio version 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Make sure, gradle isn't in offline mode
2. Clean project
3. Remove .idea and .gradle folders from your project
4. Invalidate caches and restart
5. Sync gradle and rebuild project